# How to use redis pub-sub channel with expire?

Tags: redis, vert.x

Does redis support pub-sub channels with expiration ttl?

We are using redis-cli with vertx : https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/

```
 redisClient.subscribe(channel, result -> {
            if (!result.succeeded()) {
                log.warn("subscribe failed msgId={}", msgId, result.cause());
                message.fail(500, String.format("retrieve conversation %s failure", msgId));
                return;
            }

            // redisClient.psetex(channel, 28000, ... handler -> {});   ???
```

is this the way to go?

**PS:**  I m referring to the TTL of the channel reference itself.

Comment: Is the TTL you are referring to for the messages sent/received by pubsub ?

Comment: ah thanks for asking, i didnT notice it was not clear. i m referring to the channel itself.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such feature in Redis. [Here](https://making.pusher.com/redis-pubsub-under-the-hood/) is a blog that describes the inner workings of Redis PubSub.